# how to set a breakpoint in all the functions inside a dynamic library

Tags: xcode, macos, lldb

How may I set a breakpoint that matches C functions like:
open(int x)
openX123(unsigned arg)
open(char *file, uint flags)
testOpen(char *file)

inside a .dylib library?

Using `br set -r open` matches hundreds of C/C++/ObjC functions/methods.

FYI. I'm using OSX and lldb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

break set has a `--shlib` (`-s`) option that will limit the breakpoint to a particular shared library.  Note, this option can be repeated multiple times if you have more than one library you'd like lldb to look in.